# Loading JSON from Python into DataTable of Google's Annotated Chart

Tags: python, json, google-visualization, web.py

I have collected pollution data with python and stored it in a MySQL table.
Now i would like to display this in one of Google's [Annotated charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart).

When I and display the chart on a web page, rendered via a web.py server, I get a blank chart.
Nothing, just white space. Its probably either the way the JSON string is formatted, or the way i tried to load it into the DataTable object.

Here's how I am currently converting the MySQL data to a DataTable object and rending it to the web with Python and web.py:

1. Query the data from mysql with python. That returns this:

   ```
   [(datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 23, 2, 1, 3), 329),
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 23, 1, 1, 4), 337),
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 23, 0, 1, 5), 353),
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 22, 23, 1, 4), 377),
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 22, 22, 1, 7), 404),
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 22, 21, 1, 5), 402),
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 22, 20, 1, 4), 391),
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 22, 19, 1, 3), 385),
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 22, 18, 1, 3), 389),
    (datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 22, 17, 1, 3), 400)]
   ```
2. Then use the gviz_api python library from google to define the table

   ```
   description = [("Time","datetime"),
                  ("PM25 Pollution","number")]
   ```
3. Then create the DataTable object and load the data

   ```
   data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(description)
   data_table.LoadData(data)
   ```
4. I am using web.py to render all this and get it on the web, so i get the JSON string with:

   ```
   return data_table.ToJson()
   ```
5. This is the JSON string returned:

   ```js
   {"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,23,2,1,3)"},{"v":329}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,23,1,1,4)"},{"v":337}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,23,0,1,5)"},{"v":353}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,22,23,1,4)"},{"v":377}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,22,22,1,7)"},{"v":404}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,22,21,1,5)"},{"v":402}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,22,20,1,4)"},{"v":391}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,22,19,1,3)"},{"v":385}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,22,18,1,3)"},{"v":389}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014,1,22,17,1,3)"},{"v":400}]}],"cols":[{"type":"datetime","id":"Time","label":"Time"},{"type":"number","id":"PM25 Pollution","label":"PM25 Pollution"}]}
   ```
6. Then I send the string to this template to be rendered:

   ```html
   $def with (jsonDataString)

   <html>
     <head>
       <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
       <script type='text/javascript'>
         google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['annotationchart']});
         google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)

         function drawChart() {
           var data = new google.visualization.DataTable($jsonDataString);

           var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

           var options = {
             displayAnnotations: true,
           };

           chart.draw(data, options);
         }
       </script>
     </head>

     <body>
       <div id='chart_div' style='width: 900px; height: 500px;'></div>
       <!-- Output the string to see if its there-->
       $jsonDataString
     </body>
   </html>
   ```

When I load the page, see a blank white space, 900 x 500 pixels, and then the JSON string as above. So i know what I am getting the JSON string, but i'm new to charts and not sure if its properly formatted. I didn't change anything, just let the gviz_api Python library do the work.

I also tried:

```js
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable.fromJson($jsonDataString);
```

But to no avail.

Note: the `$jsonDataString` is escaped by the web.py Templating system, and replaced by the string shown above of course.

I have done some searching around with google, and stack overflow and can't seem to find what the problem is. If you have any suggestions or advice, they would be greatly appreciated. I will try to elaborate, if you think you could help, but don't quite understand from what i have written here.

**EDIT #1**
Interesting. This is actually what i get when i view source in Chrome. This is whats is rendered from web.py's Templator:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['annotationchart']});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)

          function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({&quot;rows&quot;:[{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,18,1,4)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:383}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,17,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:386}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,16,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:366}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,15,1,4)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:333}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,14,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:329}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,13,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:320}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,12,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:316}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,11,1,4)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:302}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,10,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:296}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,9,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:296}]}],&quot;cols&quot;:[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;datetime&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Time&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Time&quot;},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;number&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;PM25 Pollution&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;PM25 Pollution&quot;}]});

            var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            var options = {
              displayAnnotations: true,
            };

            chart.draw(data, options);
          }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id='chart_div' style='width: 900px; height: 500px;'></div>
    <!-- Output the string to see if its there-->
    {&quot;rows&quot;:[{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,18,1,4)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:383}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,17,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:386}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,16,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:366}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,15,1,4)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:333}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,14,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:329}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,13,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:320}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,12,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:316}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,11,1,4)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:302}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,10,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:296}]},{&quot;c&quot;:[{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;Date(2014,1,23,9,1,3)&quot;},{&quot;v&quot;:296}]}],&quot;cols&quot;:[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;datetime&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;Time&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Time&quot;},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;number&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;PM25
    Pollution&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;PM25 Pollution&quot;}]}
    </body>
    </html>
```

I think I see what's going on here. web.py's Templator must be replacing the "s with websafe quotes. That obviously wont with with JS. I guess all there is to do is find how to disable websafe quote rendering in web.py. (Or find some other work around.)

Thanks Anto, for your suggestion. I was silly not to actually check the output!

**Edit #2: SOLVED**
To make it so web.py doesn't render the websafe quotes, I simply replaced:

```
$jsonDataString
```

with

```
$:jsonDataString
```

In the web.py template.
Found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/webpy/yubRpchAYao/4Y8Cm5Dj3XcJ)

Comment: Thanks Martijn, i'm new to stackoverflow markup

Comment: Code blocks in lists are always a little more confusing; you need to double the indentation.

Comment: fyi, using your json string (without python) and html code I got valid chart

Comment: Could you check what code do you get after rendering of the template?

Comment: Sure, i'll be home in an hour, and post the code that gets rendered.

Comment: Solved it. I just used $:jsonDataString instead on $jsonDataString
To render the quotes as quotes and not websafe quotes. I'll update the post.

Comment: Make your solution an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking to get from a (python) pandas dataframe -> json -> a google.visualization.DataTable in JavaScript ...

```
#imports
import pandas as pd
import json
# create df for test
cols = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
vals = [["work",2,3],["play",5,6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols)


# Send df to google.visualization.DataTable via json
# ..parse column data (I'm only using numbers and strings)
# ..google allows ['string', 'number', 'boolean', 'date', 'datetime', and 'timeofday']
# ..but no dates for json
# .. ..one-liner here
cols = [{"id": col,
        "label": col,
        "type": "string" if df[col].dtype == 'O' else "number"
        } for col in df.columns]
# ..use pandas to get at the row data
jsdata = json.loads(df.to_json(orient="split"))["data"]
# .. ..multi-liners seem easier to read...
rows = []
for row in jsdata:
    row = [{"v": val} for val in row]
    rows.append({"c": row})

#.. I'm using dumps to show the value but you probably want to use 
#.. dump in practice
to_google = json.dumps({"cols": cols, "rows": rows})
print(to_google)

In [1]:
{"cols": [{"id": "col1", "label": "col1", "type": "string"}, {"id": "col2", "label": "col2", "type": "number"}, {"id": "col3", "label": "col3", "type": "number"}], "rows": [{"c": [{"v": "work"}, {"v": 2}, {"v": 3}]}, {"c": [{"v": "play"}, {"v": 5}, {"v": 6}]}]}
```

On the .js side, the key lines are:

```
// parse the responseText from your xhttp GET
_jsonIn = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
// drop it into your table
dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(_jsonIn);
```

[image: transported table]